# JS-IPFS preload error client.js:12 WebSocket connection to 'wss://node3.preload.ipfs.io/p2p/

Tags: javascript, typescript, ipfs, js-ipfs

Hello I have an issue with preload p2p wss from js-ipfs defaults.
Normally everything works perfectly, but defaults goes wrong.

```
client.js:12 WebSocket connection to 'wss://node3.preload.ipfs.io/p2p/QmY7JB6MQXhxHvq7dBDh4HpbH29v4yE9JRadAVpndvzySN' failed:
```

Error has no end. All requests has byte data but this very first which starts on beginning fails.

My IPFS implementation:

```
  async start(): Promise<void> {
    if (this.node) {
      console.log('IPFS already started');
    } else if (window.ipfs && window.ipfs.enable) {
      console.log('Found window.ipfs');
      this.node = await window.ipfs.enable({ commands: ['id'] });

    } else {
      console.time('IPFS Started');
      try {
        this.node = await this.ipfs.create();
        console.timeEnd('IPFS Started');
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('IPFS init error:', error);
        this.node = null;
      }
    }
  }

  getIpfs(): null | PromiseType<ReturnType<typeof Ipfs.create>> {
    return this.node;
  }
```

`getDefaultOptions()` on preload fails. Is there anything I should pass in `create()` method?

Comment: I get this same repeating error in the browser. The IPFS implementation works fine, but this error is a bit unsettling. It just fills up the console log.

Comment: Thank you for comment, could you help to connect to go-ipfs api?